# When Scrolling a table view cell out of view, cell text changes

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView and i programatically add two buttons to the cell. 1 button adds to the cells text ( counts up ) the other subtracts 1 (counts down). However, lets say i add 4, the cell's text will be `4`, but when i scroll that cell up and out of the view, when it comes back down into view, the cells text is back to `1` which is where it started out. The same happens if i add(it does the same if i subtract also) to the cells text and switch pages and then go back to the table view. Here is the `cellForRow`:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         newBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(260,20,55,35)];
         [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(subtractLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [newBtn setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [newBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:newBtn];

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(200,20,55,35)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];
    } 
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    cell.imageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
    cell.textLabel.text = [cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks:D

[image: Here is the screen Shot of the cell]

**Methods for buttons**

```
    - (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{    
    cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];    
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] +1];
}  

- (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender
{
    cell = (UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];        
    if ( [[cell.textLabel text] intValue] == 0){ 
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] +0];
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] -1];
        //[myTableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Comment: That's because cells are reused, and you need to (re)set things (labels, buttons) in cellForRowAtIndexPath to ensure that, when the cell is reused, all components on the cell are correct. For example, if you have a button on the cell, and its text is different from row to row, then that text needs to be reset in cellForRowAtIndexPath; if the text is the same for all rows, obviously there is nothing to worry.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help peter! how do you recommend i reset the cells text in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this, where you are storing the values outside the cells. This is because the cells get reused and are not good long term storage.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {

         subBtn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
         subBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
         [subBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(200,20,55,35)];
         [subBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(addLabelText:indexPath.row) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         [subBtn setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [subBtn setEnabled:YES];
         [cell addSubview:subBtn];
    } 

    // we're loading the value from the array each time the cell is displayed.
    cell.textLabel.text = [cellLabelValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

 - (IBAction)addLabelText:(int)currentRow{    
     NSString *newValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[cellLabelValues objectAtIndex:currentRow] intValue] +1];
    // we update the value in the array since this is the source of the data for the cell
    [cellLabelValues replaceObjectAtIndex:currentRow withObject:newValue];
    // now reload to get the new value
    [myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: ALso, thank you for the help! :D when both you and peter say i have to set the values that change, what do you guys mean by that? Thanks again!

Comment: I think that your value is stored in the *cells* array, right? After you change the value in the *cells* array, call ReloadData to update the table's cells. I think that's the core answer.

Comment: Yes thats right! Oh! Geeze i think i got it! Thanks bud ill try it now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: alright, both of the buttons have their own methods. I added the `[myTableView reloadData];` line in those. However all it did was make the buttons not work. Am i putting them in the wrong spot? Sorry for all the noobish lol.

Comment: You can't use the table's cells to store your values. You need to place the updated values into an array (You said you have one named *cells*, right?) So, just update the value in the *cells* array and then call reloadData. If that doesn't make sense I'll post an example.

Comment: okay i kinda have an idea! Could you please post an example if it isnt too much trouble? Thank you!

Comment: okay perfect! shall i replace `cellLabelValues` with an array, or `cell.textLabel.text`? I tried an array and the app crashes :( and with cell.textLabel.text, the app has warnings and doest work either!

Comment: cellLabelValues would be the name of the MUTABLE array you've declared to hold these values.

Comment: right my array is mutable! and it just crashes when i try to press the button. Im not sure, but when i checked the log, it said: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FinalCartViewController addLabelText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6880900'`

Comment: sorry if this is quite a hassle! :/ for you

Comment: okay how do i accept that? haha and ill try to keep this super fast for ya bud!:D

Comment: Hey richard, would it be easier to programatically add a UILabel and just update that instead? Thanks

Comment: I got it!!! :D i just got rid of the `cell.textLabel` and added a UILabel and it fixes the problem!! :D THanks for all the help!