# Check Boxes in CollectionView are changing positions when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have collectionView (3*3) with Images I am loading from server and I placed a checkBox in the top left corner of each cell so that I can select the cells and based on the selected cells I will get ids for the respective cells images(ids coming from server) and I am able do everything right. But, the problem is if there is are 20 images and if I check the 5 random cells which are loaded for the first time and when I scroll down to select other cells 5 other random checkBoxes are already checked and if I scroll up again some other 5 random cells are checked. It appears that the checked checkBoxes are changing positions because of the dequeue reusable property in the cellForItemAtIndexPath of UICollectionView DataSource method..

I have no Idea how to overcome this problem. Please help me If any one knows how to do this. I am posting below the code I wrote so far and some simulator screenshots for better understanding of the problem...

## EditCertificatesViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

protocol CheckBoxState {
    func saveCheckBoxState(cell: EditCertificateCell)
}

class EditCertificatesViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var certificatesCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var certificatesArray = [Certificates]()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         self.title = "Delete Certificates"
         navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
     }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         return certificatesArray.count
     }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "editCertificate", for: indexPath)  as! EditCertificateCell
         if let certificateURL = URL(string: certificatesArray[indexPath.item].imagePath) {
             cell.certificateImage.af_setImage(withURL: certificateURL)
         }
         cell.certificateId.text = "\(certificatesArray[indexPath.item].imageId)"
         cell.selectCertificate.customBox()
         if selectedCellIndex.contains(indexPath.item) {
             cell.selectCertificate.on = true
         } 
         else {
             cell.selectCertificate.on = false
         }
         cell.selectCertificate.tag = indexPath.item
         cell.checkState = self
         return cell
       }
}

extension EditCertificatesViewController: CheckBoxState {

    func saveCheckBoxState(cell: EditCertificateCell) {

        if cell.selectCertificate.on == true {
            cell.selectCertificate.on = false
        } 
        else {
            cell.selectCertificate.on = true
        }

        if selectedCellIndex.contains(cell.selectCertificate.tag) {
            selectedCellIndex = selectedCellIndex.filter{$0 != cell.selectCertificate.tag}
        } 
        else {
            selectedCellIndex.append(cell.selectCertificate.tag)
        }
        print("Status1 \(selectedCellIndex.sorted { $0 < $1 })")
        //        certificatesCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

## EditCertificateCell:

```
import UIKit

class EditCertificateCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var certificateImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectCertificate: BEMCheckBox!
    @IBOutlet weak var certificateId: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectCertificateBtn: UIButton!

    var checkState: CheckBoxState?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectCertificateBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:event:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton,event: UIEvent) {
        self.checkState?.saveCheckBoxState(cell: self)
    } 
}
```

Comment: How are you selecting the tableview cells and changing the checkbox colour ?

Comment: You need to store checked item in your Model or save checked item in array and you need to check in `cellForItemAt` whether current indexPath exist in array or model. if exist then set checkmark image or not then set uncheck image.

Comment: @Amit I am using collectionview cells and I not selecting cells I am using BEMCheckBox library and color changes as I have set the checked and unchecked colors in storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable UITableView's cells reloading when scrolling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539977/how-can-i-disable-uitableviews-cells-reloading-when-scrolling-it)

Comment: Another possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304636/when-scrolling-a-table-view-cell-out-of-view-cell-text-changes?rq=1

Comment: you must have added the selection and deselection method to it? Please Update your question with that.

Comment: @Kuldeep Can you please post your code again I would like to try it..Thanks.

Comment: @finngu my concern is totally different from the above two you have mentioned. But thanks for the suggestions mate...

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla I am sure it is different, but ultimately it boils down to cell recycling and I am sure these other two questions can help you solve your problem. Also they might help others, who want to learn about the concepts of UITableView and UICollectionView.

Comment: @finngu But, this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52074887/9326980] and this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075673/9326980] helped me solve my problem.. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

CollectionView dequeue's your cell. To rid of this you need to maintain array of selected certificates. Follow below procedure.

1. Create an array `arrSelectedIndex : [Int] = []`
2. In `cellForRow`,

   - First check either current index in available in `arrSelectedIndex` or not? If yes, then make your cell as selected otherwise keep it uncheck.
   - Give tag to your check button as like this `buttonCheck.tag = indexPath.item`
3. If you wanted to select images on check button action, do below.

   - Get the button tag  let `aTag = sender.tag`
   - Now check wther this index is available in  `arrSelectedIndex` or not? If yes then remove that index from from the `arrSelectedIndex` otherwise append that array.
   - reload your cell now.
4. If you wanted to select images on didSelectItem instaead check button action, do below.

   - Now check wther this selected index (indexPath.item) is available in  `arrSelectedIndex` or not? If yes then remove that index from from the `arrSelectedIndex` otherwise append that array.
   - reload your cell now.

---

As this procedure is lengthy so I can only explain you how to do this. If need further help then you can ask.

Comment: this is working fine but every time when checking a checkBox I am reloading collectionView this makes all the images flash for a sec..

Comment: what if I don't call collectionView.reloadData() in the checkBox method

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla In that case your collection button appeared be in old state i.e. initially your image is unselected, now when you select any image every thing work in the code but on UI it still shows same image as unselected. To update data you need to reload it.

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla your UI is flashed bcz you reloading your entire collectionView. So better if you use [reloadItemsAtIndexPaths](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditemsatindexpaths). It is fast and avoid your screen to flash. It is the only procedure that you have to do.

Comment: I checked everything and it is working very fine for me even without calling collectionView.reloadData() or may be in my case I don't need to call it I think.. But, I don't what do you mean by "UI shows the same image as unselected".. I am not selected the image but the checkbox which is in the cell and it updates when I tap and thats all I want. btw you can check my code(edited) in EditCerttificatesViewController and EditCertificateCell how I did it..

Comment: Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me with this problem mate I might not have done this without your help..

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. Because you are reusing the cells.

Consider this. You select the first 2 cells, and now scroll down. This function of yours will be called `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`. Now this might get the views from the first 2 cells, that you had selected, and their checkboxes are already selected too.

You need to unset them, and set them, depending upon their last state.

I would recommend adding another property `isCertificateSelected` to your `Certificate` model. Each time the user taps on a cell, you retrieve the model, and set/unset this `bool`. When `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called, you retrieve the `isCertificateSelected` again, and set the checkbox accordingly.

Comment: @VenkateshChejarla Updated the answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @dahiya_boys answer worked out for me but I would like to try to do it your way too....

Answer (score 1):

Create an array `var Status1CheckList = [Int]()`

And in `cellForItemAt indexPath` check the condition like

```
if Status1CheckList.contains(indexPath.row) {
    cellOfCollection.CheckBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "check"), for: .normal)
} else {
    cellOfCollection.CheckBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheck"), for: .normal)
}
cellOfCollection.CheckBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cellOfCollection.CheckBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.checkList), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And checklist method, After selecting button reload the collectionview

```
 @objc func checkList(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if Status1CheckList.contains(sender.tag) {
            Status1CheckList =  Status1CheckList.filter{ $0 != sender.tag}
        } else {
            Status1CheckList.append(sender.tag)
        }
        print("Status1 \(Status1CheckList.sorted { $0 < $1 })")
    self.collectionviewObj.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: this is working fine but every time when checking a checkBox I am reloading collectionView this makes all the images flash for a sec..